# Problema no Ruby on Rails 3.2 - Ele mostra no HTML comandos do Git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

Quando dou um push para o servidor (estou usando jenkis e o gitlab ) quando vou verificar no endereço ele mostra vários erros.
[www.scti.uenf.br](http://www.scti.uenf.br) esse é o site que está com problema.

`Ruby 1.8.2`
`Rails 3.2`
`Jenkins`
`Gitlab`

Screenshot do problema[image: Screenshot do problema]

Comment: Isto é por que tu fez `merge`, `rebase` ou alguma outra operação para o seu branch atual e não resolveu os conflitos, quando o git não consegue fazer o processo todo sozinho adiciona essas marcações para facilitar a resolução dos conflitos. Só tu resolver os conflitos e pronto!

Comment: @BrunoCésar coloque seu comentário como resposta :)

Answer (score 1):

Isto é por que tu fez `merge`, `rebase` ou alguma outra operação para o seu branch atual e não resolveu os conflitos antes de efetuar o `commit` --> `push`.

Quando o git não consegue fazer o processo todo sozinho adiciona essas marcações (veja [Conflitos de Merge Básico](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Ramifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-Branching-no-Git-B%C3%A1sico-de-Branch-e-Merge#Conflitos-de-Merge-B%C3%A1sico)) para facilitar a resolução dos conflitos.

A solução é, então, solucionar estes conflitos([how to resolve conflicts](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)) e depois de resolvidos, enviar ao `remote`.

Comment: O problema é que o error só está aparecendo no servidor, local está funcionando. Como poderia arrumar isso no servidor, desde já sou grato.

Comment: @RodolfoPeixoto o jenkins clona de qual *branch*? Faça um clone "do zero" do mesmo *branch* e veja como está o código nele. Você não conseguirá mais usar ferramentas de *merge*, pois já foi feito *commit* e *push*, ou seja, já foi dito ao git que não existe conflito. Então, faça o clone do *branch* e veja os arquivos que estão com problema, ok?

Comment: O jenkins está clonando do master, fui verificar no gitlab só tem o master, fui onde estava aparecendo os heads errors e tals, editei, porém ele não clonou corretamente para o servidor. Será que pode ser error no servidor ou no jenkins? 
Fiz do zero como havia dito, mas no servidor só aparece HEAD o hash do commit. :X
Muito obrigado pela paciência

Comment: @RodolfoPeixoto cara, meio difícil onde está GERANDO o erro, o que consigo te falar é o que está na resposta mesmo, ou seja, que não foram resolvidos conflitos em algum momento. Verifique o *job* do Jenkins, veja como ele é executado. O que havia para testar é fazer o mesmo clone que o jenkins faz e testar localmente, então você consegue validar o que está errado, se o local do jenkins ou se o remoto, entendeu?

Comment: Entendi sim, vou fazer a verificação agora, muito obrigado pela ajuda!